# Text based adventure in Python

Tags: python

I made this game and I want for the user to have to get a saddle before they are able to leave with the horse right now this always prints("Lose") even when I have the saddle and enter yes for the raw_input.

```
##Text adventure##
import time, datetime, sys, random
keepGoing = True
saddle = False
def typer(what_you_want_to_type):
  for letter in what_you_want_to_type:
    sys.stdout.write(letter)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(random.random() * 0.1)
typer("""You are at home eating a taco when suddenly there is a 
great flash of light in the sky.""")
print("")
##Places and there descriptions go here##
home = ("Home", "You are at home.")
farm = ("Farm", "You are on the farm herding sheep while eating a taco")
field = ("Field", "You are in a corn field and you dropped your taco")
ranch = ("Ranch", "You are on the ranch")
##Dictionary of were you are and were you can go based on were you are##
transitions = {
    home:(farm, field),
    farm:(home, ranch),
    field:(home, ranch),
    ranch:(farm, field) 
    }
##Current location##
location = home

##Main game loop##
while keepGoing:
    print("")
    print location[1]
    time.sleep(3)
    print("\nYou can go to these places:")
    ##Adds a number to each place##
    for (i, t) in enumerate(transitions[location]):
        print i + 1,t[0]
    ##Obviously where you choose to go##
    choice = int(raw_input("\nGo to "))
    location = transitions[location][choice - 1]
    if location == field:
        take = raw_input("Take a horse?")
        if take == "yes" and saddle == True:
            print("win")
            keepGoing == True
        else:
            print("Lose")
            keepGoing = False

    if location == ranch:
        saddle == True
        print("found a saddle.")
```

Comment: You set `saddle = False` at row 4 and never change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

```
saddle == True
```

I guess you meant:

```
saddle = True
```

So saddle is actually never changed to True

Hope that helped :)
Cheers,
Alex